# How to search a hard drive for a directory name using DOS

Tags: dos

Is there a way to find a file on the C:  of a computer , using a DOS command, without having to CD to the root of the C: drive?  I would like to do it using the DIR and the FINDSTR  command only.

Ultimately, my goal is to search for a file and then store the parent directory name in a ENV variable without changing directories and hopefully without creating a temp file.

Comment: Is writing a small console app out of the question? Also, what should it do if your search finds multiple files with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the complete file name with directory in a useable form.

```
dir C:\FILENAME.EXT /s /b
```

Comment: yes indeed.  thats it.  i didn't realize the /b  option did that.  thanks, thats what I needed.

Comment: @djangofan, /b just lists the results in `bare format`. See `dir /?`. It is not required. The answer should indicate this.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [How to find a file in MS-DOS.](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000309.htm)

```
dir *bob*.* /s
```

See also [List of DOS commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands)

Answer (score 0):

c:> findstr /s /i  *.ext
REM finds in drive c: every file called *.ext containing  (case insensitive)